# PHP User Group Levels

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a small cms project my database fields are as follows

Levels Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `security_level` (
  `user_level` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `level_title` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

VALUES
1, User
2, Moderator
3, Administrator
```

User table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` text,
  `security_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

What I am trying to do is create a function that I can include on my member area pages, so if there level_id is 1 but the page requires level_id 2 it will simply redirect them, by default the level is set to 1...

I am using this to make sure they are logged in or redirect

```
<?php

if (logged_in()) {} else {

    redirect("login.php");
}
?>
```

but I would like to restrict access to certain pages based on level_id

Comment: Are you making use of sessions to store the security level at the time of login ?

Comment: How `logged_in` function is defined?

Comment: @Amaru look at the answer that I posted and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be something like this. The function below returns true or false and takes 2 arguments: `$page_level` and `$user_level`:

```
function user_has_permissions($user_level, $page_level)
{
    // a user can access page less than or equal to their level
    if ((int)$user_level >= (int)$page_level)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am calling this function `user_has_permissions()` and not `logged_in()` because the user might be logged in but they may not have permissions to a page that belongs to a different level.

Then on the page, in order to user this function.

```
$page_level = "2";    // define page level on each page
// get the user level from sessions
if (!user_has_permissions($_SESSION['user_level'], $page_level))
{
    header ("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
// code after successful permissions checking goes here
```

This is a simple implementation but you are probably looking for something like Access Control Lists (ACL).